# telegram api php sendMessage

Tags: php, telegram

Использую API telegram для отправки сообщений в канал. Нужно получить результат, как показано на примере ниже, что бы вверху был текст, внизу изображение.
При использовании метода sendMessage и вставке ссылки в текст поста получаю похожий  результат, но эта ссылка отображается также в тексте. Вопрос: правильный ли метод использую, как можно побороть отображение ссылки в тексте?

[image: пример]

Comment: Нашел решение на англ. стаке - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46780833/10391576

Answer (score 0):

Может стоить попробовать отправлять не сообщение с ссылкой на изображение, а изображение с текстовым описанием:
https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/api#sendphoto

Comment: Да дело в том, что так и делал, но нужно теперь изменить вывод.